# Codeigniter and javascript-add dynamic input and radio fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

hi guys I am pretty newbish in javascript and php for that matter. I am making a page where user will choose either to create a radio or input fields for others to solve.

Everything works fine except, when I save the form, fields are not in the order I added them because I first loop over the 'input' fields and then over the 'radio' fields. I know this is probably not the way to do it, feel free to give me an alternative.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

VIEW

```
  <h1>Add questions</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
<div id='pit'>
       <span id="add_input"><a href="#" class='button' style='font-size:1.5em;'><span>&raquo; add input </span></a></span><br>
        <span id="add_radio"><a href="#" class='button'style='font-size:1.5em;'><span>&raquo; Dodaj yes/no question</span></a></span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $this->uri->segment(3); ?>" />
   <input id="go" class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
var a=0;
$(function(){
    $('span#add_input').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#pit').append('<p><strong>Pitanje #' + count + '</strong>'+ '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" /></p>' );
        a=count;
        document.write(a);
    });
});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    $('span#add_radio').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#pit').append('<p><strong>DA/NE #' + count + '</strong>'+ '<input id="radio_' + count + '" name="radios[]' + '" type="text" /></p>' );
    });
});</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$id=$this->input->post('id');
    if($_POST['fields']){
                    foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key=>$value ) {
                        $tip='input';
                        if($value!=''){
                            $this->page_model->add_questions($id,$value,$tip);
                        }

                    }
                }
                if($_POST['radios']){


                    foreach ( $_POST['radios'] as $key=>$value ) {
                        $tip='radio';
                        if($value!=''){
                            $this->page_model->add_questions($id,$value,$tip);
                        }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work.

Maintain the same `count` variable in the JavaScript to keep track of which input is created.

Instead of using `name="fields[]"`, use `name="field_' + count + '"` so you can iterate with a loop in the controller.

VIEW

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
var a=0;
$(function(){
    $('span#add_input').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#pit').append('<p><strong>Pitanje #' + count + '</strong>'+ '<input name="field_' + count + '"  type="text" /></p>' );
        a=count;
        document.write(a);
    });

    $('span#add_radio').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#pit').append('<p><strong>DA/NE #' + count + '</strong>'+ '<input name="radio_' + count + '" type="text" /></p>' );
    });
});
</script>
```

CONTROLLER

Use a regular expression to extract the necessary values.

```
$inputs = array();
$id=$this->input->post('id');
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/(field|radio)_([\d]+)', $key, $matches)) {
        $tip = $matches[1];
        $count = $matches[2];
        $inputs[$count] = array($id, $value, $tip);
    }
}
```

Loop through the new `$inputs` array to call your add_questions method.

```
ksort($inputs);
foreach($inputs as $array) {
    $id = $array[0];
    $value = $array[1];
    $tip = $array[2];
    $this->page_model->add_questions($id,$value,$tip);
}
```